# HTML to PDF at ASP.NET Core on Linux Environment - What lib to use?

Tags: linux, html, c#, .net, asp.net

I'm currently looking on an ***ASP.NET Core*** library capable of managing **HTML/CSS** code to **PDF** rendering, but the case here is that it needs to work on **Linux**. *Docker* image on Linux, more specifically.

- I've implemented `ABCPdf`, it was really nice but unfortunately the HTML feature is Windows only.
- I've tried `JsPdf` and `Html2Pdf` (JavaScript approach), it worked but there are so many limitations and the font is always cut off on new PDF pages.
- I've tried `Puppeteer Sharp`. At first I thought that I got what I needed, but it requires Chrome/Chromium installation on Docker image, and so on, the memory usage would raise up. It didn't work too.

So, given the past few years, I've been searching for an option here. No success so far. If anyone could give any idea, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution some months later.

The library [**iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core**](https://github.com/VahidN/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core) could reach exactly what I was looking for, generating the PDF inside docker Linux from HTML string. I have used ASP.NET Core 3.1.

There are some few code samples there on description test methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying the DocumentConverter class from LEADTOOLS. (Disclosure: I’m a LEAD employee).

There’s a tutorial titled [Convert Files with the Document Converter - .NET Core](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/documents/cross-platform/dotnet-core/convert-files-with-the-document-converter.html) that describes how to use this class.

In particular, look at the function named `static void ConvertToDocument()` in the tutorial, which produces PDF files from any document format.

If you would like to try it, there’s a free evaluation edition on [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: I appreciate your answer but unfortunately I can't pay for that. It's too expensive as well. If it was a free library I would give it a try, for sure :)